# Polymer and Google Index

Tags: polymer, search-engine, google-search-console, polymer-starter-kit

I am developing a Polymer app at http://alpha.drjoke.com

I tried submitting to Google Index using the Webmaster Tools.

It appears that Google can render my app correctly.

However, it seems that Google is not picking up any textual data. It is not indexing any words from my app. It even complains that it cannot detect structured data and that I should start adding HTML.

Am I understanding things correctly? What can I do to have Google correctly index my Polymer app.

Comment: Does your website has a [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) file ? Which informations does the webmaster tools testing utility gives for this file ? And about [sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) ?

Comment: I just added robots.txt and sitemaps. I also did "Fetch as Google" and submitted the page. Please note that I currently have only one page, which is http://alpha.drjoke.com and I just want to understand if Google can see textual content of my page. Index Status also shows that 0 pages are indexed.

Fetch as Google appears to correctly render my page. However, when I get a warning from Search Appearance that "We do not detect any structured data on your site".

Comment: About [structured data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), this is logical: this is about semantically structured data (formats such as microdata, RDFa, JSON-LD, even RDF seems to be accepted). This is not about Web components. However, a Web component page is supposed to be crawled.

Comment: Is there a way to TEST for sure that Google can see the "textual content" within my Polymer site?

Comment: Index Status shows that 0 page is indexed.

Whereas Sitemap shows 1 URL has been submitted. (This test site only has 1 URL.

Comment: As far as Google analyses the URL, it should find the content. In the "Exploration" part of the Webmaster tools, you should have more infos. If there is no error, all should be fine. I guess you used the ''Explore like Google'' option. Google indexed properly a [personal page](http://bdulac.github.io/polymeria/) with web components. However, the actual data was in the main page: it is possible that the Googlebot does not properly crawls imported pages such as in your case. In fact, if the bot followed the imported link, several URLs should be indexed.

Comment: Even if the of HTML imports for Web components is supported by Google via the Polymer project, it is still [controversial for Mozilla](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/12/mozilla-and-web-components/): if crawling does not work with the Googlebot, the solution might be doomed...

Comment: Hope you will get a more advised reaction than mine: I am personally very interested in the answer. It is very important before actually using the technology in production...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a few days, but it now seems that Google can see the textual content on my Polymer site.